# Can a hometheater be connected to PC?

Tags: laptop, audio, tv, speakers, sound-card

I am planning to buy Samsung 32J4300 TV. And I want to connect Logitech Z-906 5.1 Speaker System with it.

**Q1.** Can it be connected to my TV. I am asking this because I have tried to connect my Creative speakers to my brother's TV but the TV does not have 3.5mm port. So couldn't connect.
According to the site Logitech Z-906 supports :Digital optical cable, digital coaxial cable, RCA cable

So I guess it can be connected to Samsung 32J4300 but please I need some body's expertise to make myself sure.

**Q2.** Can it be connected to my laptop. I have Asus X550LC-160D. The laptop has **only** **one** **black** **colored** audio input (3.5 mm). But Logitech Z-906 has **3 ports (green, black & orange)**. Can it be connected to my laptop. Or I need to buy an external sound card?

**Q3.** If I need to buy an external sound card then how to connect it to my laptop? Are all external sound cards USB based?

Thanks in advance.
Sumit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because q1 is off topic and q3 is a shopping recommendation

Comment: A very interesting question and a very understandable problem. I would also like to know the answer to this question. I can't say I never wondered the same thing before. +1

Comment: @Dave I understand your concern, but it's my opinion these sub-questions are a reasonable necessity to fully answer the question. Also, q3 is in my opinion NOT a shopping recommendation. This question seems valid to me.

Comment: To utilize the 5.1 capability of the speaker system, the laptop would need a digital audio output (either coax or optical), or an external sound adapter with digital audio output or discrete 5.1 analog out.